# А как все-таки Cors нас защищает?

Tags: веб-программирование, http, безопасность, cors

Почитал я разные статьи про Cors, но до конца не понял, от чего эта политика браузеров нас защищает. Опишу, как я понимаю ситуацию. Пусть я захожу на вредоносный сайт. Сайт делает запрос на сервер ВК и вуаля - от моей страницы появляется объявление "Кокаин по закупочным ценам" или что-то вроде того. Из статей в интернете я понял, что уязвимость именно такого рода. То есть, если у нас открыта сессия с каким-то сайтом (ВК например) и, допустим, такая вещь как Cors не существует, тогда, якобы можно нарваться на описанную выше ситуацию и если бы не Cors, то по интернету было бы не безопасно ходить, а мошенникам было бы очень легко гнать трафик. Возможно я неправильно понял уязвимость, но что-то у меня не сходится. Пусть авторизационная сессия, например ВК, работает на кукисах. А для каждого сайта свои куки. Я захожу на вредоносный сайт и у него моих ВК кук нет. Как тогда он сделает запрос будучи не авторизованным? Или ему придется "украсть" куки другим способом? Что мошенникам тогда мешает с их сервера отправить запрос на сервер ВК с моими куками?
Суть вопроса в следующем. Опишите, пожалуйста, кратко, от чего нас защищает Cors и что было бы если бы не Cors.

Comment: Без CORS вредоносный сайт может отправить запрос к ВК, а браузер автоматически прицепит ВК-куки к этому запросу, красть куки не требуется

Comment: @andreymal, хорошо, вот я зашел на вредоносный сайт, там формочка, типа введите свой ид вконтакте и вы выиграете миллион. Я ввожу, он тут же отправляет на сервер вк запрос на пост в каком нибудь сообществе рекламы (пусть для этого эндпоинта нужен текст поста, ид того кто постит и авторизационные куки). А как браузер ее прицепит? И зачем? Непонятно.

Comment: Также не особо понятны эти мутки с OPTIONS запросом перед, например, пост запросом с контенттайпом application/json. Зачем этот OPTIONS? От чего он спасает?

Comment: Просто возьмёт и прицепит, потому что запрос на сайт изначально всегда сопровождается куками, это уже потом начали добавлять всякие защиты из-за злоумышленников. Зачем - потому что иногда взаимодействие между сайтами это полезно

Comment: OPTIONS нужен чтобы получить CORS-правила перед выполнением реального запроса и, если CORS запрещает делать запрос, заблокировать его

Comment: @andreymal а вот например есть у меня REST API. Мне все равно кто к нему обращается. Есть у меня клиент, там есть форма логина/пароля, туда пользователь их введет, получит jwt токен и будет дальше ходить с ним на мой апи. Вопрос, зачем мне тут Cors? Я понимаю, что для корректной работы, мне его необходимо настроить, если клиент у меня на отдельном домене. Но он в ситуации, когда куки у меня не используются (рест апи же, json) Cors от чего-то меня спасает? Или в данном случае лишь вызывает досадные лишние телодвижения?

Comment: @andreymal то есть, нет jwt токена - откуда ты пришел - неважно, до свидания. Есть - велком. Весь вопрос в том, зачем в такой ситуации Cors.

Comment: Для API без кук — наверное незачем

Comment: @andreymal, то есть вся эта система именно для такого более старого веба, для которого характерна, например, авторизация на куках, сессии и тд, верно?

Comment: `то есть вся эта система именно для такого более старого веба`. Не только. Авторизации вообще может не быть, а ограничить запросы нужно только своим сайтом. Например открытый адрес получения региона по IP, и вы хотите пользоваться этим только на своем сайте.

Comment: @TotalPusher тогда ребята, которые хотят использовать халявно мой АПИ для получения региона по IP пойдут ко мне не с клиента, а с сервера. А все эти ограничения действуют только на клиентской стороне. С сервера - ходи не хочу. Верно ведь?

Comment: Да верно. Но такое злоупотребление блокируется на основе IP.

Comment: @TotalPusher хмм, верно. Если они пойдут с клиента, то я только буду видеть, с какого ip пришел клиент. Я не буду знать, что это не мой клиент, а чужой чел использует мой классный АПИ не заплатив например. Так получается?